# Joining a temporary DataFrame to permanent DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to join a predefined Data Frame to a temporary Data Frame which is located within a loop. My code template is as follows:

```
df1_date = pd.date_range('2008-01-01', '2017-01-01')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=final_date)

    #A loop:
       dates = pd.date_range('2008-01-01', '2009-01-01')
       df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=dates)
       df1 = df1.join(df2, how='left')
```

When the loop runs for the first time the index values of DataFrame which is calculated in loop joins with the DataFrame which was defined in begining. But when the loop runs for the next time it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Valuation'], dtype='object')
```

The next time loop runs it calculates values for the next time period and I want it to join with the permanent Data Frame, rather than giving the above error.

Comment: Try this with `merge`, `left_index=True`?

Comment: Got this error : pandas.tools.merge.MergeError: Must pass right_on or right_index=True

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory -- joining to `df2` the first time adds a column `Valuation` to `df1`. The next time you try to join, both `df1` and `df2` have a column named `Valuation`. Pandas doesn't want to overwrite the existing column, so you need to provide `lsuffix` and `rsuffix` to add to the column name: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: After doing as said, I end up with 7 different columns. But how would I get a one single column of Valuation. (Index don't overlap)

Comment: Then you're doing the wrong operation. You don't want a 7-way join -- you want to *concatenate* all your `df2`s first (`pd.concat`), then join that to `df1` all together.